# gdal warp is not creating a file

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdalwarp

i am trying to change the EPSG from 4236 to 32614 and also change the height but the gdal warp is not creating any file. i tired with translate it works but the image looses it value so i am trying with warp but its not creating any file. i am working on the python console form QGIS

```
import gdal
fn = "D:\\sat1\\281.1.tif"
out = "D:\\test1\\281.2.tif"
gdal.Warp(out, fn, srcSRS = "EPSG: 4326", dstSRS = "EPSG: 32614", width = 1134, height = 1134)
```

Comment: Have you tried without two dots in the filename

Comment: what do you mean by two dots

Comment: `281.1.tif` is a bad filename. Try `281_1.tif`

Comment: The default of option -format seems to be "None" https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#WarpOptions. I think you should add GTiff because that seems to be what you want.

Comment: I also believe that the syntax `srcSRS = "EPSG: 4326"` is wrong. Use single quotes and remove the space character. Actually the whole script is probably rubbish but I am not good at Python. I can see in working examples things like `ds1 = gdal.Open('tmp/testgdalwarp_gcp.tif')`, not `ds1="tmp/testgdalwarp_gcp.tif"`.

Comment: also add `gdal.UseExceptions()`  after your `import gdal` for better error messages

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import gdal #or from osgeo import gdal
import os

fn = "D:\\sat1\\281.1.tif"
out = "D:\\test1\\281.2.tif"

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite fn out -s_srs EPSG:4326+5773 -t_srs EPSG:4979"
print(cmd) #see wether everything is fine
os.system(cmd) #execution by passing the command to the system
```